# Firefox 4 not handling escaped urls properly

Tags: firefox, url, escaping

I am sending email from my server whose source looks like this:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/myurl?email=my%40my.com">http://mydomain.com/myurl?email=my%40my.com</a>
```

In all other browsers when I click on the link in the email, it opens to :

```
http://mydomain.com/myurl?email=my%40my.com
```

However, in Firefox 4, the link is interpreted as:

```
http://mydomain.com/myurl?email=my@my.com
```

This obviously breaks the script at the URL. Why does Firefox put the @ sign instead of using the escaped form and how can I make behave as it should?

**Edit:**
Seems like this is a problem only when Hotmail is used as a client to open mails inside Firefox.

Anyone else know of this issue with Firefox and Hotmail?

Comment: Why does it break your script? Isn't the `@` received by your server?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your intention is to open the email client on the OS when you click the link then you should be using `mailto` in `<a href=....>` like

```
<a href="mailto:my@my.com?subjeck=your subject here&body=http://mydomain.com/myurl?email=my%40my.com">Send email</a>
```

This should handle any in-compatibilty of browser vs. email client.